# Cannot connect remotely to ubuntu using hostname on win7

Tags: networking, vnc, hostname

I am trying to connect to my ubuntu pc from my windows 7 pc using ultravnc (on LAN). It works when I use the IP address of the ubuntu pc, but when I use its hostname it doesn't work at all, I cant even ping its hostname using windows pc, but I can ping its IP address.

I have enabled remote desktop on ubuntu to allow remote control and that works because I can do it using IP address.

I have also tried disabling firewall using "sudo ufw disable" and it still doesn't work.

I have also tried using automatic dns with DHCP, and I have tried setting it manually as well and it still doesn't work.

Also to note that I have a wired connection (lan) and VPN connection (internet), but that doesn't matter I gues because this is only important for LAN.

I have installed samba as well.

Please help me by giving me a detailed explanation on what should I do, because I am a total beginner in Linux and I am still experimenting with everything but I cant figure out what to do here. I have tried using mint linux and connection using its hostname works, but I would still preffer to use ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on the networking, but unless you have a DNS server, I'm not sure how your Win7 can resolve the Ubuntu hostname.

Either setup a DNS server, or force the windows hotsts file ( c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts ) by adding :

your.ubuntu.box.ip     your.linux.box.hostname

Comment: You are 100% correct, even if you are not sure about it. ;)

Comment: Yes I work at a hospital and we have a dns server it is at 192.168.29.1. I have tried using the automatic dns (which is recognised to 192.168.29.1) I have also tried setting the DNS manually to the server address and it still doesnt work. But how come it works on Mint Linux without any previous settings? I just run ultravnc from my win7 and just enter the hostname for the mint linux pc and it works like a charm, but it doesn't work for ubuntu that way.

Comment: Also to say that we have over 400 computers running in the hospital so only our servers have static IP addresses, rest of the computers use dynamic IP addresses so the only option in this case is to use ultravnc to connect to a PC using its hostname, which works perfectly on windows machines

Comment: Ok, let's try to understand ;)

Comment: First question : what are the results of "uname -a" on your Mint and on your Ubuntu boxes ? Second question : what hostname do you use from your Win7 box to access your Mint and your Ubuntu boxes ? Unless you added your ubuntu box to the DNS configuration (in the DNS server itself), resolution can not be achieved. Can't figure out of your Mint box can be resolved.